# What's the difference between the Oracle SYS and SYSTEM accounts?

Tags: oracle, administration, database-administration

What are the differences between the Oracle SYS and SYSTEM built-in accounts?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

SYS owns the oracle data dictionary. Every object in the database (tables, views, packages, procedures, etc. ) all have a single owner. For the database dictionary, and a whole lot of special tables (performance views and the like) are all owned by the SYS user.

The SYSTEM user is supposed to be the master DBA user, with access to all of these object. This reflects an early, and long time, Oracle security design philosophy. You build the application using one user, then create a second with access (select, update, delete) but not drop privileges. This gives you a "super-user" access to your schema without being able to destroy it accidentally. Over the years, thing have been added to the SYSTEM account that may have needed to be in the SYS account. But very few people want to give out access to their SYS account if they don't have to.

Answer (score 16):

`SYS` can `connect AS SYSDBA`, `SYSTEM` cannot.

`SYSDBA` privilege is required to perform certain administrative tasks, like `CREATE DATABASE`and `DROP DATABASE`, and query any tables despite `GRANT`'ed permissions on them.

In fact, whenever you connect as `SYSDBA`, you become a `SYS`.

Comment: I have just connected to the default XE under SYSTEM "as sysdba". What puzzles me tho is that I did not set pw to the SYSTEM account and I am able to use it with the pw I set up for SYS. (I know very little about Oracle.)