# Getting "java.sql.SQLException: ORA-28009: connection as SYS should be as SYSDBA or SYSOPER" in groovy

Tags: java, oracle, groovy, sysdba

Code is as follows -

```
import groovy.sql.Sql

def driver = "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
def jdbcUrl = "jdbc:oracle:thin@myhost:1521:MYSID"
def sql = Sql.newInstance(jdbcUrl , "sys", "password", driver)
```

But I am getting following error

```
Caught: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-28009: connection as SYS should be as SYSDBA or SYSOPER

java.sql.SQLException: ORA-28009: connection as SYS should be as SYSDBA or SYSOPER

        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:445)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:389)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:382)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.processError(T4CTTIfun.java:600)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.processError(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:445)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:450)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:192)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOAUTH(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:380)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOAUTH(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:760)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:401)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:546)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:236)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:521)
```

I tried replacing user as 'sys as sysdba' as mentioned in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10101517/how-to-connect-in-java-as-sys-to-oracle).

I also tried using

```
Properties props = new Properties()
props.put("user","sys")
props.put("password", "password")
props.put("internal_logon", "sysdba")
jdbcUrl = "jdbc:oracle:thin@myhost:1521:MYSID"
def sql=Sql.newInstance(jdbcUrl,props)
```

as suggested [here](http://johnsjavapda.blogspot.in/2014/09/groovy-how-to-login-to-oracle-as-sys-as.html)

but here I am getting

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why are you trying to log in as SYS in the first place?  That is an incredibly powerful account that should be used very, very infrequently.  Unless you are building an application specifically for DBAs to manage a database and building a screen in that application that actually requires the elevated privileges of SYS, you wouldn't want to use that account to connect to the database.  You'd want to use a much less privileged account.

Comment: @JustinCave I am doing something on that lines only and I need sys as sysdba to do that.

Comment: do not log on as sys through an application, create a user, grant them DBA and connect with them

Comment: Why should there be any difference? [Oracle docs](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-faq-090281.html#05_11) also says it can be done but doesn't seem to work and I wish to know why if anyone has prior experienced this.

Comment: In the last example where you have the "internal_logon" property, are you supplying the password for `SYS` or `SYSDBA`? Or have you tried both?

Comment: Listen to @JustinCave, he is giving good advice. And worth noting is that `SYS` and `SYSTEM` [are different users](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/915853/whats-the-difference-between-the-oracle-sys-and-system-accounts). Don't use `SYS` in an application.

Comment: What error you got when trying http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10101517/how-to-connect-in-java-as-sys-to-oracle

Comment: @BobJarvis the password corresponds to sys user.

Comment: @Jayan that link corresponds to Java. This is a similar issue but in groovy. As i said in question I to use `sys as sysdba` in username. No luck. Gives invalid logon.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The following **does** work. Only difference is the driver name

```
import groovy.sql.Sql

def driver = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
def jdbcUrl = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@oraclehost:1521:SID"
def sql = Sql.newInstance(jdbcUrl , "sys as sysdba", "syspassword", driver)
```

Comment: Yup that worked. As it turned out password file was corrupt. Thanks.

Comment: oracle password file - http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/dba007.htm#ADMIN10241

Comment: Hm.. in that case your "sqlplus login" would have been failing?

Comment: Not necessarily: SQL*Plus login can use OS group membership.

Comment: Username needs to be `sys as sysdba` instead of `sys`.

Comment: I search many of answers. this is the one that actually works. Many Thanks